# How to include multiple inputs in a foreach statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have two input fields that a user can repeat to insert multiple records in a single form submission. I'm currently using a foreach loop to loop through one of those inputs and grab the value however now I need to loop through both inputs at the same time to save the data together.

I want to loop through both the `input-type` & `input-label` together and save the stored values to the db.

I guess I could create two foreach loops but that just seems like a horrible way to go about things.

**Form -**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('savePage') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <ul class="field-list">
        <li v-for="(input, index) in inputs">
            <input type="text" name="input-type[]" v-model="input.one" style="display: none">
            <input type="text" name="input-label[]" v-model="input.two" placeholder="Label name">
            <p><span class="codesnippet">text</span></p>
            <button class="p-btn secondary" @click.prevent="deleteRow(index)" >Remove field</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller -**

```
public function saveAtt(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->input('input-label') as $label) {

        $field = new Attribute;
        $field->page_id = 1;
        $field->label = $label;
        $field->type = 2;
        $field->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('indexPage');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$types = $request->input('input-type');
foreach ($request->input('input-label') as $i => $label) {
    $field = new Attribute;
    $field->page_id = 1;
    $field->label = $label;
    $field->type = $types[$i];
    $field->save();
}
```